# SQL Server Compact 4.0 deadlocking on __SysObjects Index with ReadCommitted transactions

Tags: sql-server-ce, deadlock

While investigating a SQL Server Compact timeout/deadlock issue I was able to replicate the issue with 2 readcommitted transactions calling a single query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE (FK_Id = 1);
```

> Table name = __SysObjects, Conflict type = s lock (x blocks), Resource = RID: 1278:2

There is an index on `FK_Id` and a simpler query not using the index isn't affected by the lock contention.

```
SELECT *  
FROM [MyTable];
```

Removing (and recreating) the index also seems to resolve the deadlock issue, though I'm able to restore the original database file to get this behavior.

My question is, why is this happening and can I do anything about it? On it's face, it appears to be an issue with SQL Server Compact (read-only transactions shouldn't cause deadlocks right?) but I'm a out of my depth at this point.

According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172932(v=sql.110).aspx record 1278:2 on __SysObjects has an exclusive lock causing the issue, I just don't know what 1278:2 means or what to do with that knowledge.

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable] 
(
  [Id] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY,
  [FK_Id] int NOT NULL,
  [Title] nvarchar(255) NULL,
  [TS] rowversion NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX [IX_FKTable_FKId] ON [MyTable] ([FK_id] ASC);
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTab_FKID] FOREIGN KEY ([FK_Id]) REFERENCES [ParentTable]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the columns?

Comment: @ErikEJ I've just tried this and continue to get errors when querying specific columns

Comment: What data type are those columns? Table structure??

Comment: @ErikEJ Updated. I've queried against Count(*), *, and each specific column with the same result. Querying with an execution plan that uses the index versus one that doesn't changes if the deadlock occurs.